# php while loop table repeating fix

Tags: php, mysql

I have following do while loop be it keep on repeating the table for each record how to fix it? full table repeat for each record.
Also for every row fetch can I add

```
<table width="1510" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2"  class="table table-bordered" >
       <tbody>
       <form name="f1">
       <? $counter = 1;
    $total_marks = 0;
    $total_obtain = 0;
    while($row_rsDept = mysql_fetch_array($rsDept))
        {
        if($counter === 1)

        {
    ?> 
         <tr>
           <th width="71" rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h4>Sr. No</h4></th>
           <th width="229" align="right" valign="top" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
           <th colspan="8" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col"><h3>Detail of Marks</h3></th>
         </tr>

         <tr> 
           <th rowspan="2" align="left" scope="row"><h4>Subject</h4></th>
           <td colspan="2" align="center"><h4>Thoery</h4></td>
           <td colspan="2" align="center"><h4>Practical</h4></td>
           <td width="134" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><h4>Marks Obtain</h4></td>
           <td width="144" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><h4>Max Marks</h4></td>
           <td width="137" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><h4>Remarks</h4></td>
           <td width="137" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><h4>Grace Marks</h4></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td width="134">Obtained Marks</td>
           <td width="144">Total Marks</td>
           <td width="143">Obtained Marks</td>
           <td width="153">Total Marks</td>
           </tr>
             <? } ?>    
         <tr> 
           <th align="left" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
           <th align="left" scope="row"><?php echo $row_rsDept['SUBJECTS']; ?></th>
           <td><?php echo $row_rsDept['THEORYOBTAINEDMARKS']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row_rsDept['THEORYTOTALMARKS']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row_rsDept['PRACTICALOBATINEDMARKS']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row_rsDept['PRACTICALTOTALMARKS']; ?></td>
           <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_rsDept['MARKSOBTAINED']; ?></td>
           <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_rsDept['MAXMARKS']; ?></td>
           <td align="center" valign="middle"><span class="style8"><?php echo $row_rsDept['REMARKS']; ?></span></td>
           <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_rsDept['GRACEMARKS']; ?></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <th colspan="6" align="right" valign="middle" scope="row"><h4>Total</h4></th>
           <td align="center" valign="middle"><span class="style8"><?php echo $row_rsDept['TOTALMARKS']; ?></span></td>
           <td align="center" valign="middle">=total of above ( )</td>
           <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>

 <?php
      } ?> 

         <tr>
           <th colspan="10" align="left" valign="middle" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <th colspan="8" align="left" valign="middle" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
           <th align="left" valign="middle" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
           <th align="left" valign="middle" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <th colspan="8" align="left" valign="middle" scope="row"><br></th>
           <th align="left" valign="middle" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
           <th align="left" valign="middle" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
           </tr>

       </form>
     </table>
```

I tried to fix but not working for me

Comment: You forgot to increment/decrement your `$counter` variable

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do? What would you expect to happen? What is happening instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside loop you need to increment counter variable 
Inside loop  add this line

```
$counter++;
```